# Finding parents without children in TODO state in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm using the TODO keyword for tasks.

Oftentimes, I need to find parent tasks with no children in TODO state (could be DONE, just not pending). These parent tasks are themselves marked as TODO.

Is there any search query (sparse tree match query) that would show me only those?